# Can only extract some of the data from a JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I am importing a JSON file from an API ('http://api.eia.gov/').  The following three lines work great for getting the time series data into a data frame:

```
d = json.loads(requests.get(page).text)
df = pd.DataFrame(d['series'][0]['data'])
df = df.set_index(df[0])
```

My issue is extracting the other values/elements not related to the data which appears at the end of the dict. Here is some of the output when I type in d in the terminal.

```
In [72]: d
Out[72]: 
{'request': {'command': 'series', 'series_id': 'STEO.COPR_AG.M'},
 'series': [{'series_id': 'STEO.COPR_AG.M',
  'name': 'Crude Oil Production, Algeria, Monthly',
  'units': 'million barrels per day',
  'f': 'M',
  'copyright': 'None',
  'source': 'U.S. Energy Information Administration (EIA) - Short Term Energy 
             Outlook',
  'geography': 'DZA',
  'start': '199401',
  'end': '201806',
  'lastHistoricalPeriod': '201803',
  'updated': '2018-07-10T12:02:18-0400',
  'data': [['201806', 1.04],
   ['201805', 1.02],
   ['201804', 0.99],
   ['201803', 0.99],
```

So using the df from above gives me the dataframe data for the time series.  But I can't figure out how to get some of the other variables - like the 'name' or 'lastHistoricalPeriod'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
I need to include series as well...not sure I understand the logic as to why, but this works.

```
In [90]: x = d['series'][0]['name']
In [91]: print(x)
Crude Oil Production, Algeria, Monthly
```